# Regex for "must contain a character outside of this range"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a regex syntax equivalent to "must contain a character outside of this given range"?

For instance, if I want to match any string that contains a character which is not any of these: 1,a,@

...but can also contain the characters in the range?

Examples:

1111 - Would not match

11a@ - Would not match

1a@b - Would match

cdef - Would match

I thought perhaps (?=.*[^1a@]) would do the trick, but no dice.

Comment: "*I thought perhaps `(?=.*[^1a@])` would do the trick*" - it should work just fine. Can you [edit] your question to include the JS code of how you were trying to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a lookahead, you could match at least a single occurrence of `[^1a@]` in the string.

**Note** that `[^1a@]` can also match a newline or a space.

```
^.*?[^1a@\r\n].*$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AaioPP/1).

If you don't want to match only spaces, you use `\s` in the negated character class `[^1a@\s]` to exclude a whitspace char only being a valid match.

Example getting the whole match:

```js
const regex = /^.*?[^1a@\r\n].*$/;
["1111", "11a@", "1a@b", "cdef"].forEach(s => {

  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    console.log(s)
  }

});
```

Example testing if the string contains any char other than the listed in the character class:

```js
["1111", "11a@", "1a@b", "cdef"].forEach((s) => {
  if (/[^1a@]/.test(s)) {
    console.log(s);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `[^1a@]` do?

Comment: @CherryDT If you would use it to test if the string contains `[^1a@]` it will. If you want to match the whole string, you can use the pattern I posted.

Comment: Yes, that's true...